# How to add group image views inside scroll view dynamically

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I'm working on grouping the similar images and putting it inside `scroll view`. So there will by multiple groups of similar images.Friends, which layout and view I prefer. I'm new to the dynamically creating the view. Here is the structure.
        --------------------------------------

```
    |      ||      ||       |
    |image ||image ||image  |
    |  1   ||   2  ||     3 | 
                                         ----------->Group1
    |      ||      |
    |image ||image | 
    |   4  ||   5  |
    --------------------------------------
    |      ||      ||       |
    |image ||image ||image  |
    |  1   ||   2  ||     3 |
                                              ----------->Group2
    |      ||      |
    |image ||image | 
    |   4  ||   5  |
    --------------------------------------
    |      ||      ||       |
    |image ||image ||image  |
    |  1   ||   2  ||     3 |
                                            ----------->Group3
    |      ||      |
    |image ||image | 
    |   4  ||   5  |
```

Comment: use recyclerview or listview

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ListView, and store custom list items. Or Inside your XML layout file use this architecture to store your views

```
ScrollView
  LinearLayout(Vertical)
    Group1
    Group2
    Group3
```

Where you store you linearLayout, and keep adding your group(s) to it. And also store you group view (some kind of layout) to add image to each group. This way, whenever you add a group to your LinearLayout it will add it at the end, and it will be scrollable. In terms layout width and height, make it fill_parent, to use the full potential of the screen.